# How to create animated gif file like in mega.co.nz

Tags: gif, animate

What is the best way/software to create animated gif file like in mega.co.nz.
This is sample files:

[image]
[image]

Thanks for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a video and then extract the frames from that video into individual images, then put each image into an animated gif software. It will make a GIF look just like the video it came from.